# CSS/PHP: How to make the next div appear on the side instead

Tags: php, html, css

I'm stuck on the project that I am doing right now. I made a php that outputs a single div, this div will output multiple times depending on the number of items that I have in my database, my problem is that, I want the next div to be outputted on the left side of the previous div, just like this:

```
 -----   -----   -----
|div 1| |div 2| |div 3|
 -----   -----   -----
 -----   -----   -----
|div 4| |div 5| |div 6|
 -----   -----   -----
```

But I can't think of any ways to do it, it's outputting as it should be like this:

```
 -----
|div 1|
 -----
 -----
|div 2|
 -----
 -----
|div 3|
 -----
and so on...
```

Hope you guys can help me, thanks.

PHP:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM content");
    if ($results) { 

    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
        echo '<div class="content">'; 
        echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```

CSS:

```
.content{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #F0F0F0;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #F8F8F8;

}
```

Comment: `.content { width:33%; float:left; }`? although with your other css, it may need to be a little less then `33%`

Comment: or `display: inline-block;`. or use table (ugly but works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need a wrap div for `class="content"`

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM content");
    if ($results) { 

    //fetch results set as object and output HTML
    while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
        {
        echo '<div class="box"><div class="content">'; 
        echo '</div></div>';
        }
    }
```

and the css

```
.box{
     width: 33.333333333%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     float: left;
     }
```

here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/taunj8m0/2/

Answer (score 0):

[take a look at this jsfiddle I have done for you](http://jsfiddle.net/391L2q3f/)

I have used CSS [floats](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp) to get what you want

```
#container{
    width: 330px;
    height: auto;
}

.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```